# Controlling Multithreading in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, ios5

I am a newbie in iPhone App development and I have a problem with thread controlling.

I have set two threads:

- first one updates a LABEL (LABEL1) after a specified time interval [it works fine]
- another does the same [updates another LABEL(LABEL2)] and is (controlled) started & stopped with a button press event:

  - 1st button-press starts the thread & makes the LABEL2 visible
  - 2nd press stops its execution & makes the corresponding LABEL2 invisible... and this way be controlled..

Button has a TUCHUPINSIDE event, and I am working with iPhone simulator.

It is working fine when the button is pressed normally (slowly), but when double-clicked or continuously clicked on the button and its execution state comes- then the corresponding LABEL2 is being updated faster then its interval.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, don't update any UI on any thread other than the Main Thread, you will have unpredicted results.

Why are you doing this on another thread? Are you just experimenting?

Also, I wouldn't advise using NSThread (neither do Apple). There are many more higher level concurrency API's you can use in objective-C, such as NSOperations, GCD....

Comment: Thanks bandejapaisa,    1.Yes it was just an experiment.  2. I've never worked with those API's. So, can you tell me which of the concurrency class will be the most effective for any situations?